# Crystal summary and percents

Tags: crystal-reports

I have a Crystal Report v 9.2.2 and I have three summaries at the end of each group; count of IEP students, count of non-IEP students, and total number of students. For an example, for one group (a class) I have 25 students. 4 Students are IEP, 21 are non-IEP. So I tried to create a formula to calculate the percentages, but the percents are wrong.

sum({@IEP}) % count({Mytable.student_id})

Manually, the math says 4 / 25 * 100 = 16, but when I use the formula above I get 11

I don't think it's a formatting problem.

Answer (score 0):

Check reset value in "Create running Total Field" for the count.

[image]

Or

reset the count in the formula.

Answer (score 0):

Your math is right, just do the same thing in the code/formula. The following works for a group based on {YourGroupField} and gives the percentage to one decimal point:

```
local numbervar IEPstudents := sum({@IEP},{YourGroupField}) //get number of IEP students in group
local numbervar TotalStudents := count({Mytable.student_id},{YourGroupField}) //get total students in group
local numbervar ThePercent := (IEPstudents / TotalStudents) * 100;
totext(ThePercent,1) + '%'
```

Alternatively, you can keep the formula numeric and add the percent symbol and formatting in the field's format editor.

Comment: Thanks to both of you for an answer. The reset was fine. When I used the variables I printed out all the pieces and found that because I lacked {YourGroupField} in the sum and count, my values were way off. It's all fine now.